Error loading JSON schema from https://json.schemastore.org/<manifest.json>: Not Found
Description:
I'm encountering an issue with loading a JSON schema in my development environment. Here are the details:
Problem:
When I configure my JSON schema in Visual Studio Code using the following settings:
"json.schemas": [
    
    {
        "fileMatch": [
            "*.json"
        ],
        "url": "https://json.schemastore.org/<manifest.json>"
    }
],
"tabnine.experimentalAutoImports": true,
"[python]": {
    "editor.formatOnType": true
},
"workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+",
"liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
"chatgpt.lang": "en",
"liveServer.settings.donotVerifyTags": true,
"window.zoomLevel": -1,
"docker.languageserver.diagnostics.instructionJSONInSingleQuotes": "ignore",
"http.proxySupport": "off",
"[cypher]": {
    

    "editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": true
}

}

I receive the following error message:
Problems loading reference 'https://json.schemastore.org/<manifest.json>': Unable to load schema from 'https://json.schemastore.org/<manifest.json>': Not Found. The requested location could not be found. The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. (768)

Context:
I suspect this error might be affecting my .cypher files as well, as I'm using JSON schema for validation and highlighting in my editor setup.
Question:

How can I resolve this error and successfully load the JSON schema?
If the schema at https://json.schemastore.org/<manifest.json> is no longer available, where can I find a suitable alternative schema?
Are there any alternative configurations or settings adjustments I should consider to ensure my .cypher files are correctly validated and highlighted?

Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
What i tried:

Checked URL: I verified that the URL https://json.schemastore.org/\<manifest.json> is correctly formatted and accessible.
Alternative Schemas: I attempted to find alternative JSON schemas that could be used instead of https://json.schemastore.org/\<manifest.json>.
Configuration Adjustments: I reviewed and adjusted my Visual Studio Code settings related to JSON schema (json.schemas).

Expectations:

Successful Schema Load: I expected that configuring the JSON schema as specified ("url": "https://json.schemastore.org/<manifest.json>") would allow my IDE to load and use the schema without errors.
Impact on .cypher Files: I anticipated that resolving this schema loading issue would also resolve any related issues affecting my .cypher files, ensuring proper validation and highlighting.


Any url with <> must be encoded. The link you provided for manifest.json is invalid and doesn't exist. manifest.json itself, doesn't exist on schemastore.org either.
